# Need help getting a child within a node to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to get the data from a child node in an array in state into a new array in order to map and display on the DOM. This is the code that I have:

```
    const { tour } = this.state;
    const gearArray = Array.from(tour.gears);
    const showTourInfo = () => gearArray.map((label, value) => (
        <Link to={`/gear/${value}`} >{label}</Link>
    ));
```

This is my data structure:

```
-MOq_JbS669VyEbv4CXt
  description: "Iron Maiden Tour"
  firebaseKey: "-MOq_JbS669VyEbv4CXt"
  gears
    -0
     -label: "Jazzmaster"
     -value: "-MOhOuYl1_EZ-xkeI03a"
    -1
     -label: "JMP"
     -value: "-MOlWQ9FDs_2wO3SL2hb"
  name: "World Tour 2020"
```

I want to take the label/value and map those. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `gearArray.map((label, value) => (` to `gearArray.map(( { label, value }) => (`

Comment: I get back undefined

Comment: Why is this tagged with `json`. There is no JSON here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```js
const { tour } = this.state;
    const gearArray = Object.values(tour.gears);
    const showTourInfo = () => gearArray.map(({label, value}) => (
        <Link key={label} to={`/gear/${value}`} >{label}</Link>
    ));
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I got: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. Tour is showing in state. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: could you please give me tour object in json format, because I thought from your post that gears is an object

Comment: -MOq_JbS669VyEbv4CXt
  -description: "Iron Maiden Tour"
  -firebaseKey: "-MOq_JbS669VyEbv4CXt"
  -gears
    -0
     -label: "Jazzmaster"
     -value: "-MOhOuYl1_EZ-xkeI03a"
    -1
     -label: "JMP"
     -value: "-MOlWQ9FDs_2wO3SL2hb"
  -name: "World Tour 2020"

Comment: Sorry it's formatted better above. My data is stored in Firebase, I wrote a function to push the data to state in that structure. I appreciate your help!

Comment: welcome, one last thing could you please give me the result of console.log(tour);